# How to open file from VSCode file explorer in same window

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Using `cmd+shift+e` I can highlight the file explorer tab and then use vim keybindings to select a given file. However, I've only figured out how to open a selected file in a new editor pane (`Ctrl+Enter`).

Is there a shortcut to open it in the same pane? Can I change the behavior of the `Ctrl+Enter` shortcut? A pointer to the right docs would also be helpful.

Comment: If you want to re-use the active editor for a new editor, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60216168/vscode-open-files-not-in-a-new-tab-reuse-current-tab/60218148#60218148

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This closest action is `filesExplorer.openFilePreserveFocus`, which is bound by default to `Space`.

This will open the file currently selected in a new tab, but it won't move your cursor to it.

You can use the `cmd+shift+e` keybinding to get back to your editor, though!

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_window-management)

> The settings `window.openFoldersInNewWindow` and `window.openFilesInNewWindow` are provided to configure opening new windows or reusing the last active window for files or folders and possible values are default, on and off.
>
> If configured to be default, we will make the best guess about reusing a window or not based on the context from where the open request was made. Flip this to on or off to always behave the same. For example, if you feel that picking a file or folder from the File menu should always open into a new window, set this to on.
>
> Note: There can still be cases where this setting is ignored (for example, when using the -new-window or -reuse-window command-line option).

Comment: Not quit what I'm talking about here. I've found an `explorere.openToSide` shortcut which opens the file in a split pane. My question is whether I can change this to the same pane.

Answer (score 0):

The `filesExplorer.openFilePreserveFocus` command does what you want with the limitation that it keeps the focus on the explorer sidebar. To move focus to the opened window you can utilize the fact that `workbench.view.explorer` toggles focus between editor and explorer. Together with a extension such as [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) that enables running multiple commands the desired behaviour can be achieved:

```json
  {
      "key": "enter",
      "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
      "args": {
        "sequence": [
          "filesExplorer.openFilePreserveFocus",
          "workbench.view.explorer",
        ],
      },
      "when": "explorerViewletFocus && explorerViewletVisible && !inputFocus"
  },
```