# How can I make VS Code replace the current tab instead of creating a new one when opening a file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I believe that this is not covered by the Preview feature. I simply want to open a file for editing via Quick Open (or any way?) and replace the contents of the active tab, closing the open file and replacing it with the new one.

This behavior is central to the way I edit. Currently, I'm always opening new tabs that I don't want. It's the only barrier left between Code and the way I've used Vim for 15 years. I imagine that this is scriptable, but would like to avoid going down that road. Please tell me I'm missing something.

Comment: I have the exact opposite problem. vscode replaces current tab instead of opening new tab. This only happens sometimes, seems random.

Comment: I agree with spinkus, very annoying VS Code is reusing tabs. If I wanted to close a file, I'd close a file. I think it is related to whether or not a file has been edited. Just disable workbench.editor.enablePreview

Comment: For those who end up here and want the opposite of the behavior desired in the OP, you may need to turn OFF Workbench > Editor:Enable Preview. If that setting is on, Code will replace the contents of your current tab when you open a file, unless you have edited the currently-selected open file.

Answer (score 10):

(1) The drastic approach:  search for these in your settings:

`Workbench > Editor > Limit: Enabled` enable this

`Workbench > Editor > Limit: Value` set to `1`

Drastic, because it will limit you to only `1` editor tab, probably not what you want but it does reuse the active (and only tab) of course.

(2) The macro approach:

Using a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) put this into your settings.json

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

  {
    "command": "multiCommand.openFileInActiveEditor",
    "sequence": [
      "workbench.action.closeActiveEditor",
      "workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem",
      "workbench.action.closeQuickOpen"   // if you want to close the quickopen panel immediately
    ]
  }
]
```

and in keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "alt+0",  // whatever you want
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.openFileInActiveEditor" },
  "when": "inFilesPicker && inQuickOpen"
},
```

It appears that you cannot override the usual <kbd>right</kbd> keybinding from the quickOpen panel so I set it to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> instead but you can pick whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

@Mark's answer almost gets you there, but it doesn't work with new (one tab) panes. Here's a modified version of his settings.json edit that does.

1. Install the [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) extension
2. Put this in settings.json

   ```
   "multiCommand.commands": [
     {
       "command": "multiCommand.openFileInActiveEditor",
       "sequence": [
         "workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem",
         "workbench.action.previousEditor",
         "workbench.action.closeActiveEditor",
         "workbench.action.closeQuickOpen"
       ]
     }
   ]
   ```
3. Put this in keybindings.json and replace the dummy value for the key `key` with your desired key combination

   ```
   {
     "key": "some+key+combination",
     "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
     "args": { "command": "multiCommand.openFileInActiveEditor" },
     "when": "inFilesPicker && inQuickOpen"
   },
   ```

Comment: Ah, I didn't test that - I don't frequently have only one tab open...

Comment: I was *nowhere* before your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

VSCode now has built-in support for multiple commands.

- The `multi-command` extension is no longer required.
- It seems that you can use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key instead.
- I have fixed and modified the answers to account for whether the current editor is in preview, and also so that it no longer requires the multi-command extension.

The `keybindings.json` file is now:

```json
{
  "key": "tab",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "workbench.action.closeActiveEditor",
        "when": "activeEditorIsNotPreview",
      },
      "workbench.action.acceptSelectedQuickOpenItem",
      "workbench.action.closeQuickOpen",
    ]
  },
  "when": "inFilesPicker && inQuickOpen",
},
```