# Replace existing tab in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When opening a file with Ctrl + P, I'd like it to replace my selected tab, instead of opening a new one. Any way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: There is no built-in way to do this if that current editor is not already in Preview Mode.  But see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60218148/836330 for a keybinding and macro that will do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable by adding "workbench.editor.enablePreview": true and "workbench.editor. enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": true to your settings.

Whenever you open a new file, this will replace the existing tab.

Comment: Thanks ! But I´d like to be able to chose to replace it or not, with a shortcut. Do you know of a way to implement this ?

Comment: I used to work by changing the settings, but may be there is a way with shortcut. I would be happy when someone share with us.

Answer (score -1):

This setting is found here : Files -> Preferences-> Settings